# Consolidate two csv file to generate a third csv file with selected rows from both existing csv file

Tags: shell, unix

I have written a shell script which generates the two csv fileA and fileB files. I need to add the script in the existing .ksh file which can add the 3rd column of the fileA to the column 1 of the new csv file that is going to generate and the second column of the fileB to the second column of the new csv. Is there any way to do it ?
For example.

```
fileA                      fileB 

A B C D                    1 2 3 4                

output.csv

C 2
```

using the awk command I can read the columns like :

```
awk -F" " '{print $3}' fileA.csv
```

But confused how to made the output to the desired columns.

Comment: Many ways. Sample input and output?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you like bash (or ksh), put fileB on filedescriptor number 3 like this and read a line from each file:

```
#!/bin/ksh
while read -r a1 a2 a3 a4 && read -r b1 b2 b3 b4 <&3; do
   echo $a3 $b2 
done < fileA 3<fileB
```

Comment: I tried with this but I am getting the below error :    $ while read -r a1 a2 a3 a4 && read -r b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 <$3; do
> echo $a4 $b4
> done < sample1.txt 3<sample2.txt
-bash: $3: ambiguous redirect

Comment: You mistyped `<&3` as `<$3`

Comment: Yeah thanks...It worked but now the problem is coming like I am redirecting the output to a file like this  $ while read -r a1 a2 a3 a4 && read -r b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 <$3; do > echo $a4 $b4 > done < sample1.txt 3<sample2.txt > output.csv . The result is directed to the file but the next echo command echo "Do you want to update ?[Y/N]" is also automatically redirected to output.csv . Why ? And what is the solution to close it.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are doing from a comment. Please edit your question and show the code you are using and what doesn't work so we can help out.

Comment: $ while read -r a1 a2 a3 a4 && read -r b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 <$3; do > echo $a4 $b4 > done < sample1.txt 3<sample2.txt > output.csv . The result is directed to the file but the next echo command echo "Do you want to update ?[Y/N]" read Z if [ Z==Y]; then execute some sybase queries and the input will be from output.csv file like done < output.csv >> NewResult.csv

Answer (score 1):

[cut](http://man.cx/cut) and [paste](http://man.cx/paste)

```
paste -d" " <(cut -d" " -f3 fileA) <(cut -d" " -f2 fileB)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with awk like this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{x[FNR]=$3;next} {print x[FNR],$2}' fileA fileB
```

**Explanation**

The part in curly braces following FNR==NR applies only to the porcessing of FileA. It saves the third field of FileA in array `x[]` indexed by the line number (`FNR`). The second set of curly braces applies to the processing of FileB. It prints the element of array `x[]` saved from FileA followed by the second field of FileB.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you like bash arrays, you could read the 3rd field of each row of fileA into an array A[], and the second field of each row of fileB into an array B[], then go through and print them side by side:

```
#!/bin/bash
A=($(awk '{print $3}' fileA))    # Read 3rd field of every line of fileA into array A
B=($(awk '{print $2}' fileB))    # Read 2nd field of every line of fileB into array B

for ((i=0;i<${#A[@]};i++))
do
   echo "${A[$i]} ${B[$i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not upvote this answe.

bash (version 4, I think)

```
mapfile -t a < fileA
mapfile -t b < fileB

for (( i=0, i<${#a[@]}; i++ )); do
    lineA=( ${a[i]} )
    lineB=( ${b[i]} )
    echo "${lineA[2]} ${lineB[1]}"
done
```

Ruby

```
ruby -e '
    a,b = ARGV.map {|f| File.readlines(f).map {|l| l.chomp.split}}
    a.each_index {|i| puts "#{a[i][2]} #{b[i][1]}"}
' fileA fileB
```

Perl

```
perl -lE '
    ($a,$b) = map {open my $f, "<", $_; [map {[split]} <$f>]} @ARGV;
    say "$a->[$_][2] $b->[$_][1]" for (0..@$a)
' fileA fileB
```

Comment: Ok, you've impressed me, you can stop now! :-)