# read multiple files in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have two .txt files that I want to read line per line simultaneously in .sh script. Both .txt files have the same number of lines. Inside the loop I want to use the sed-command to change the full_sample_name and sample_name in another file.
I know how this works if you just read one file, but I cannot get it work for two files.

```
#! /bin/bash

FULL_SAMPLE="file1.txt"
SAMPLE="file2.txt"

while read ... && ...
do
    sed -e "s/\<full_sample_name\>/$FULL_SAMPLE/g" -e "s/\<sample_name\>/$SAMPLE/g" pipeline.sh > $SAMPLE.sh

done < ...?
```

Comment: `FOO = bar` isn't a variable assignment in bash; has to be `FOO=bar`; whitespace matters.

Comment: See my answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730675/consolidate-two-csv-file-to-generate-a-third-csv-file-with-selected-rows-from-bo/22731312#22731312

Comment: you're right, my mistake. changed it.

Comment: (also, all-caps variable names are reserved for shell builtins and environment variables; see relevant part of POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, fourth paragraph starting with "Environment variable names" -- user applications in shell scripts [which share namespace between environment and regular shell variables] should use variable names with at least one lower-case character to avoid conflicts).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The updated version (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) does not say that. It says: "The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities." which is clearly not the same.

Comment: @OleTange, how, exactly, does this materially differ? Even as I read the current quote, only variable names containing lowercase letters are guaranteed by POSIX to not conflict with the names of environment variables honored by standard utilities, thus restricting the set of variables safe for application use _even of light of utilities extending the standard_.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It is different in the same way as should is different from can. The current phrasing does not say anything about what applications should do.

Comment: @OleTange, indeed, strictly, what's defined is which namespace is and is not safe from conflicts. That applications _should_ use a namespace which cannot conflict with those names used by the standard tools or compliant extensions of same is a statement I'm making with that definition as support; that applications _should_ follow practices that avoid potential namespace conflicts does not strike me as controversial.

Comment: @OleTange, ...for a history of community consensus on the subject, see also http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/varcap -- a timestamped history of factiods on the topic from Freenode's #bash channel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

full_sample_file="file1.txt"
sample_file="file2.txt"

while read -r -u 3 full_sample_name && read -r -u 4 sample_name; do
    sed -e "s/\<full_sample_name\>/$full_sample_name/g" \
        -e "s/\<sample_name\>/$sample_name/g" \
        pipeline.sh >"$sample_name.sh"
done 3<"$full_sample_file" 4<"$sample_file" # automatically closed on loop exit
```

In this case, I'm assigning file descriptor 3 to file1.txt and file descriptor 4 to file2.txt.

---

By the way, with bash 4.1 or newer, you no longer need to handle file descriptors manually:

```
# opening explicitly, since even if opened on the loop, these need
# to be explicitly closed.
exec {full_sample_fd}<file1.txt
exec {sample_fd}<file2.txt

while read -r -u "$full_sample_fd" full_sample_name \
   && read -r -u "$sample_fd" sample_name; do
  : do stuff here with "$full_sample_name" and "$sample_name"
done

# close the files explicitly
exec {full_sample_fd}>&- {sample_fd}>&-
```

---

One more note: You could make this a bit more efficient (and also more correct, if your `sample_name` and `full_sample_name` values aren't guaranteed to evaluate to themselves when interpreted as regular expressions, if your input file contains no literal NULs [which, as a shell script, it shouldn't], and if the arrow brackets are intended to be literal rather than word-boundary regex characters) by not using `sed` at all, but just reading the input to be converted into a shell variable, and doing the replacements there!

```
exec {full_sample_fd}<file1.txt
exec {sample_fd}<file2.txt
IFS= read -r -d '' input_file <pipeline.sh

while read -r -u "$full_sample_fd" full_sample_name \
   && read -r -u "$sample_fd" sample_name; do
  output=${input_file//'<full_sample_name>'/${full_sample_name}}
  output=${output//'<sample_name>'/${sample_name}}
  printf '%s' "$output" >"${sample_name}.sh"
done

# close the files explicitly
exec {full_sample_fd}>&- {sample_fd}>&-
```

Answer (score 7):

Charles provided a very good answer.

You could use `paste` to join the lines of the files with some delimiter (that shouldn't appear in the files):

```
paste -d ":" file1.txt file2.txt | while IFS=":" read -r full samp; do
    do_stuff_with "$full" and "$samp"
done
```

Comment: Great alternative if you want to ensure that _all_ lines are processed, even if the input files differ in line count (`paste` treats input files that "have run out lines" like an endless source of empty strings). If you use Bash, you can easily choose a delimiter that is unlikely to be found in text files in general, using an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting),  such as `$'\3'` (ASCII value 3, the END OF TEXT control character): `paste -d $'\3' ...` and `while IFS=$'\3' ...`.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU Parallel it will look like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

do_sed() {
    sed -e "s/\<full_sample_name\>/$1/g" -e "s/\<sample_name\>/$2/g" pipeline.sh > "$2".sh
}
export -f do_sed   

parallel --xapply do_sed {1} {2} :::: file1.txt file2.txt
```

The added benefit is that you get it run in parallel. Depending on your storage system this may speed up the processing: On a raid6 I have seen a 6x speedup by running 10 jobs in parallel. YMMV, so the only way to know for sure is to test and measure.

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel